# How do I generate multiple sentences from multiple regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have these seven regular expressions.

`(?:please |(?:can|could|will) you)
(?:eat|drink|pull up)
(?:this |that )?
(desert|drink|it)
(?:on|from )
(?:the |my )?
(table|chair|full ?plastic(?: plate)?|cup)`

I need to generate sentences using the words in these regular expressions like:
"Please eat this desert on the table", 
"can you eat drink this from my cup" etc..
A few more examples

please eat this desert on the table,

- please eat this desert on the table,
- Could you eat this desert on  the table,
- will you eat this desert on the table,
- please drink  this desert on the table,
- please drink this desert on the table

Any ideas please..

Comment: There are a million sentences that could satisfy what you're after. Whats you end goal?

Comment: My goal is , I need to generate sentences using only those words present in the regular expressions. Any sentence generated should have words only from the above regular expressions.

Comment: Parse the regex's to create a list of permutations, then permutate.

Comment: But, do you want all of the sentences, just a set of random sentences, or what?

Comment: I need all the sentences.

Comment: Regex is designed for processing input, not generating output. Your current patterns might incidentally only allow for a finite set of word combinations, but suppose you added a `*`, `+`, or even `.` to some part of them. It's asking for trouble, and for this reason you're not going to find a standard method of doing this. You can write your own code to parse the patterns, but at that point it won't be regex, it will be a program that consumes regex.

Comment: There won’t be any change to this regular expression. Those are fixed and I was given input in that way. I don’t mind if regex is used or some other code. If there is solution without using regex, that’s absolutely fine. I just need to generate all possible finite sentences using these words. Thank you.

Comment: In addition to my answer I might mention that there is/was Python software that takes a regex and generates strings that conform to that regex. However, I seem to remember that it generates random strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. Just understand that I won't be responsible for the consequences. :-)

Your regex seems to be merely a way of expressing alternatives for each part of a possible sentence.

```
>>> for word_1 in ['please', '']:
...     for word_2 in ['do', 'supply']:
...         for word_3 in ['it', 'something']:
...             sentence = ' '.join([word_1, word_2, word_3])
...             sentence
...             
'please do it'
'please do something'
'please supply it'
'please supply something'
' do it'
' do something'
' supply it'
' supply something'
```